# Probability of "time to deliver"

Tags: probability

I have a dataset of time for a package to be delivered to a customer. With this, given a specific package in transit for an *x* amount of time, I want to calculate the probability that that package will still be delivered and not be lost.

Some (maybe) useful info:

- 936 items
- min value: 1:18:00
- max value: 213:49:00
- mean: 42:19:57
- stdev: 37:22:55
- median: 32:30:00

please feel free to ask any questions if something doesn't make sense.

Thanks!

Comment: More useful is the fraction of the 936 items that have been lost.  What you are essentially doing is making a distribution of delivery times.  If you have waited the amount of time that $95\%$ of the packages have been delivered the chance that a package which has not been delivered has increased by a factor $20$.  This assumes that the distribution of delivery times is the same for all packages.

Comment: @RossMillikan Did you leave a phrase out of the second sentence of your comment?  I can't understand it.  Maybe the words "has been lost" should be inserted before the words "has increased by a factor $20$."

Comment: No, for example one model would be a normal distribution based on the mean and standard deviation you quote.  That is probably a bad model because the tails are longer than a normal distribution would have it, but we can use that.  Since $97.7\%$ of the area is left of mean+2 sigma, when you get to mean+2 sigma you have had $97.7\%$ of the packages delivered that ever will.  The lost ones and $2.3\%$ of the ones that will be delivered are left, which means the lost ones are about $40$ times as common in the remaining pool as they were at the start.

Comment: Thank you Ross! What would be the best approach to create a model out of this dataset (if any)?